# ranking using find_in_set

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

Trying to use this method to get the rank position of `$associateID`. Everything works except `FIND_IN_SET`. It's not reading alias1 or alias2. Does `FIND_IN_SET` work with alias's? How can I get this to work?

```
$associateID="3";

$query = "
    SELECT
        associate_ID, 
        COUNT(*) as alias1,
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
          from tableA 
          WHERE tableA.column='$associateID'
        ) as alias2, 
        FIND_IN_SET( alias2 ,
                     ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( alias1 ORDER BY alias1 DESC ) 
                       FROM tableA )
                   ) AS alias3
    from
        tableA 
    GROUP BY
        column
";
```

Comment: The query is out of logic. Drop it. And formulate the task, not the way which you select to solve this task.

Comment: Is it an alias issue?

Comment: You have to ask how to solve the primary problem, not the issue with your solution of the problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284253

Comment: I guess my question should be around using aliases in mysql. In the code above, would the alias2 have a value for the FIND_IN_SET to use?

Comment: *I guess my question should be around using aliases in mysql.* Alias cannot be used by such way.